# ajax post method not getting data in PHP page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get some data sent to a PHP page to update PHP Session variables. I have tried several different examples that I found here but just can't seem to get any to work. The data is never received on the PHP page.

Here is my Javascript/jQuery:

```
var str, ProductID, sessionValues= [];
ProductID = "1";
str = {"ProductID": ProductID, "State": "UNCHECKED"};
sessionValues.push(str);
ProductID = "2";
str = {"ProductID": ProductID, "State": "CHECKED"};
sessionValues.push(str);

var postObj = {"sessionData": sessionValues};
console.log(postObj);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType : 'application/json',
    data: {'data': JSON.stringify(postObj)},
    url: 'setSession.php'
}).done(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('FAILED! ERROR: ' + errorThrown);
});
```

This is what my data object looks like:

[image: Console image]

Then on the PHP side all I get is an error that I supplied an invalid argument to foreach. No matter how many times I repeat the `sessionValues.push(str)` my browser always reports 528 bytes sent.

```
<?php 
 $data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
 print_r($data);
 foreach ($data->sessionData as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key => $value";
 }
?>
```

Comment: *"Then on the PHP side all I get is an error that I supplied an invalid argument to foreach."* - Errr... *what* PHP?

Comment: Can you share the PHP code too?

Comment: ...nah, we'll just leave it. We're "pros", remember? @MatthewLymer we read minds and not code.

Comment: Haha, good point @Fred-ii- , reading minds makes this job easy...

Comment: Yes @MatthewLymer - I have on a few occasions, been successful in figuring out what an OP had in mind and missing code. *"Getting lucky"* only applies to *scoring*, if you know what I mean *lol*

Comment: You aren't sending json so why are you setting `contentType:'json'` ? How are you trying to receive this in php? You have a mismatch of types

Comment: opps. Forgot something. Sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `contentType : 'application/json',` because that is not what you are sending.

When you do send as `application/json` properly ... stringifying the whole object , not just parts of it, then `$_POST` will be empty and you have to access the data using `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'))`

There is also no need to stringify your other object...jQuery will form encode it for you and you can access it as array

Try

JS

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',        
    data: {'data': postObj},
    url: 'setSession.php'
}).done(function(response){
```

PHP

```
<?php 
 $data = $_POST['data'];

 foreach ($data['sessionData'] as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key => $value";
 }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! The data is now on the Php side. The output in the console is just `0 => Array1 => Array` but as long as it's there I can move on!

Comment: charlietfl posted a correct answer to the problem. Everyone else just Trumped all over the question. Meaning if you are just a clown who wants to say something then you pull a Trump.

Answer (score 0):

Since some browsers caches the ajax requests, it doesn't responds as expected. So explicitly disabling the cache for the particular ajax request helped to make it work. Try to modify charlietfl's request as below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',        
    data: {'data': postValue},
    cache: false,
    url: 'postAjaxHandling.php'
}).done(function(response){
});
```